# Bash terminal trying to run python code - why?

Tags: python, bash

I mistyped `ls` typing `sl` instead and instead of warning me that `sl` isn't installed as it used to I now get the following python code. Why is bash running python code when I type `sl`?

```
$ sl
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.py", line 123
    raise CodecRegistryError,\
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Have you checked your aliases on that system? You could also run 'which sl' and see where it's installed. Does it happen from every directory or just from the directory shown in the screenshot?

Comment: Your terminal shows you *text*, the OS X terminal lets you copy that text and paste it into your question here no problems.

Comment: @MartijnPieters how can you tell it is OS X terminal? ;)

Comment: @Kent: It's a guess only, but the font rendering feels, to my untrained eyes, OS X-y.

Comment: No, it's Ubuntu 13.04 with Adobe Source Code Pro as the monospace font

Comment: @DanielWatrous no, there's no alias. My concern is that I installed some malicious code when installing a python package as root and it hijacked my bash terminal. Is that possible?

Comment: Either way, `sl` is a mystery application that appears to try and import Python 2 code into an Python 3 environment and doesn't provide enough access to the environment to determine a locale encoding.

Comment: Your bash terminal has not been hijacked, no. A bash shell is *designed* to find commands and execute them as processes. This process is just broken, that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sl` is often a prank installed on systems that makes a Steam Locomotive drive across the screen; it usually lives in `/usr/games` on Linux boxen.  However, it's typically a compiled binary and not a Python script.  As suggested in comments, `which sl` will tell you where the `sl` script you inadvertantly ran is located, and `file $(which sl)` will tell you what sort of file it is.

It's also possibly it is a malicious program installed to attempt to do harm to your system upon you typoing `ls` as you apparently did; if true, it's a good thing it crashed (or apparently did so).  Either way, I would carefully read the script to see what it does.

Comment: I used to get a bash message which said "'sl' isn't installed on your system - to install it type 'sudo apt-get install sl'. I'm worried that I installed a python package as root and it has somehow hijacked my bash terminal

Comment: That's why I suggested you use `which sl` to see where the script is, and read it to see what it does.